# Boot disk with VMFS read/write driver

Tags: performance, raid, vmware-esxi, vmfs

I want to rule out the ESXi kernel being the cause for my terrible 15MB/s write speed on the local VMFS datastore.  I am using a Dell PERC H710 RAID controller, and would like to boot from a boot disk and perform some writes to bench mark the raid array.  Is there any boot disk that is going to support writing to VMFS?

Comment: Perhaps the ESXi install disk?

Comment: I don't think that there is any Linux-based (or so) boot disk with a write-capable VMFS driver that you can safely use. However, I guess the reason for your terrible write performance is probably that you do not have a working battery backup for the controller's cache. It will be automatically disabled then which leads to the terrible write performance that you notice.